# Gnuplot 5.0 patch lvl1 crashes on WIN 8.1

Tags: for-loop, crash, windows-8.1, gnuplot

I'm new with gnuplot loops, and I don't know why is it crashing...
I want to make a plot with 10 different .txt data files and after that 10 different plot from these .txt-s. (Sorry for my english) 
note: I am using win 8.1 -> I know I should use gnuplot with Ubuntu but that's the situation for now...

So here is my script:

```
cd'C:\RégiPC\asztal222\TDK\fittnessmodell\fittnessmodell\Incidencia s0 pk emel\001'  

set title "Fitness előny nélkül pk=0.7+=0.03"   

set term png size 1280,768

set key tmargin left                                                                                                                                  

set xlabel "Idő"                                                                                                                               

set ylabel "Populációméret"                                                                                                                           

set output "Incidencia_N_10.png"    

p for[i=0:9] 'Incidencia_'.i.'.txt'  u 1:2  title 'N'.i   
// here I want to do 10 different curves in one plot

unset output                                                                                                             

do for[i=0:9]
{
    set output 'Incidencia_minden_'.i.'.png'    
    p 'Incidencia_'.i.'.txt' u 1:2  title 'N'.i , 'Incidencia_'.i.'.txt'  u 1:3 title 'nacd'.i,'Incidencia_'.i.'.txt' u 1:4 title 'nscd'.i,'Incidencia_'.i.'.txt' u 1:5 title 'nscdplusd'.i 
    unset output
} // in this do for loop I want to do 10 different plots from 10 different .txt files
```

Please help and sorry if it is too trivial...

Thank you and Happy New Year!!!!

Comment: What means "crash"? What error do you get? Does it also happen if you have only the `plot for`, or only the `do for`?

Comment: Please post your error and any research into fixing the error.  Also see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It is crashing just after the for loop like this: [IMG]http://i64.tinypic.com/vmxaw6.jpg[/IMG]

Answer (score 1):

Good evening sir!

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and your code works fine with some change listed below.

1.) If you want to comment something you should use `#` instead of `//`.

2.) A problem occurs in the `do for` loop. You accidentally put the braces into a new line which is incorrect according to my gnuplot (version 4.6). The correct way to use it:

```
do for [i=0:9] {
    set output 'Incidencia_minden_'.i.'.png'
    p 'Incidencia_'.i.'.txt' u 1:2  title 'N'.i , 'Incidencia_'.i.'.txt'  u 1:3 title 'nacd'.i,'Incidencia_'.i.'.txt' u 1:4 title 'nscd'.i,'Incidencia_'.i.'.txt' u 1:5 title 'nscdplusd'.i 
    unset output
}
```

After these changes the code don't make any error or crash in my computer.

I don't know if this works on Windows. You have to try it. :)